# what's the meaning of virtual number of children in LinearLayout source code

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

the method of LinearLayout -- getVirtualChildCount() just return the method
 getChildCount() of ViewGroup , in note : This number might be different than the actual number  of children if the layout can hold virtual children . so what is the term " virtual children"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used by TableRow/TableLayout [according to this post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/226369):

> These methods are used by TableRow/TableLayout.
>   You don't need to worry about them, they are only meant for internal
>   use.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some search activity on it.

the method getChildCount() is for Tabular structure.

```
TableRow extends LinearLayout
```

and the method is overridden in TableRow.

```
@Override
public int getVirtualChildCount() {
    if (mColumnToChildIndex == null) {
        mapIndexAndColumns();
    }
    return mNumColumns;
}
```

the method in TableRow returns number of child including dummy child for padding purpose within row.

so I can say, it is basically number of column within that row.